# Write multiple values from json file into HTML table with Javascipt

Tags: javascript, html, json

There is a json file with multiple values. I would like to write the values from the file into an HTML table with Javascript.

---

**Here is an example:**

Json File:

```json
{
   "628e191673ae8f7750c62fce": {
     "name": "John",
     "surname": "Smith",
     "age": "24"
   },
   "628e1fd0d27981c6250d886c": {
     "name": "Fred",
     "surname": "Bloggs",
     "age": "32"
   },
   "628e20c805f38641bdc08d7d": {
     "name": "Joe",
     "surname": "Harris",
     "age": "27"
   }
}
```

The table should then look like this:

| Name | Surname | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Smith | 24 |
| Fred | Bloggs | 32 |
| Joe | Harris | 27 |

---

What is the best way for me to do this with Javascript?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break down the code into little bite-sized functions that build up the table row-by-row creating [HTML strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) along the way, and then adding them to the DOM.

```js
const data = {"628e191673ae8f7750c62fce":{name:"John",surname:"Smith",age:"24"},"628e1fd0d27981c6250d886c":{name:"Fred",surname:"Bloggs",age:"32"},"628e20c805f38641bdc08d7d":{name:"Joe",surname:"Harris",age:"27"}};

// Returns a simple cell
function getCell(data) {
  return `<td>${data}</td>`;
}

// Returns an string of cells HTML
// `map` returns an array so we need to `join`
// the elements together
function getRow(data) {
  return data.map(getCell).join('');
}

// Returns a set of rows by `mapping`
// over the values of each object, and creating
// a new row for each object
function getRows(data) {
  return data.map(obj => {
    const values = Object.values(obj);
    return `<tr>${getRow(values)}</tr>`;
  }).join('');
}

// Get the object values from the data
const objs = Object.values(data);

// Get the keys from the first object of `objs`.
// This way we don't have to hard-code the headings
// in the HTML markup
const headers = Object.keys(objs[0]);

// Construct a table using the functions
const table = `
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="headings">${getRow(headers)}</tr>
    ${getRows(objs)}
  </tbody>
</table>
`

// Add everything to a container
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', table);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #454545; width: 300px;}
.headings { background-color: #efefef; font-weight: 600; text-transform: capitalize; }
td { padding: 0.3em; border: 1px solid #efefef;}
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
- [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: Happy coding! There's quite a lot to digest there but hopefully my comments and the links to the documentation are helpful. @CharlieS19

Answer (score 0):

Well, your JSON is a bit special since your data-rows are not an array, they are properties... But you could do it like this...

```
const jsonData = {
   "628e191673ae8f7750c62fce": {
     "name": "John",
     "surname": "Smith",
     "age": "24"
   },
   "628e1fd0d27981c6250d886c": {
     "name": "Fred",
     "surname": "Bloggs",
     "age": "32"
   },
   "628e20c805f38641bdc08d7d": {
     "name": "Joe",
     "surname": "Harris",
     "age": "27"
   }
};


var firstIteration = true;

// create table element
for(var key1 in jsonData) { /* key1 will be the hex name */
  var row = jsonData[key1];

  // create tr element
  if (firstIteration) {
    for(var key2 in row) { /* key2 will be the attributes of the current row */
      // create th element with key2 as content
    }
    firstIteration = false;
  }
  for(var key2 in row) {
    // create td element with row[key2] as content
  }
  // close tr element
}
// close table element
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple way for doing it:

```js
const jsonfile = {
  "628e191673ae8f7750c62fce": {
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Smith",
    "age": "24"
  },
  "628e1fd0d27981c6250d886c": {
    "name": "Fred",
    "surname": "Bloggs",
    "age": "32"
  },
  "628e20c805f38641bdc08d7d": {
    "name": "Joe",
    "surname": "Harris",
    "age": "27"
  }
}
const parent = document.getElementById('table');
Object.keys(jsonfile).forEach(element => {
  const {
    name,
    surname,
    age
  } = jsonfile[element]
  let child = `<tr>
                            <th>${name}</th>
                            <th>${surname}</th>
                            <th>${age}</th>
                            </tr>`
  parent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', child);
});
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.